# Why didn't this character get powers when strapped in the Punch bowl?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, marvel, deadpool, deadpool-2016

Towards the end of the Deadpool movie

> Vanessa gets strapped into the punch bowl for a bit.

Earlier in the movie it was stated that the Punch Bowl is the ultimate way to unlock one's dormant mutant gene, yet she doesn't mutate.

Why is this?

Comment: Just realized that maybe she did get powers, and this was a setup to her being Copycat in the sequel.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**tl;dr:** Wade got injected with some blue gunk to activate his mutation, Vanessa didn't.

---

Wade did not get his mutant powers activated solely by being in the Punchbowl. If just being highly stressed out was all it took to trigger mutations then *lots* more people would have them. (Being in the Punchbowl is how people with COPD feel pretty much all the time.)

When he first arrived, Ajax injected him with a serum that was designed to activate any latent mutant powers. It was only after this serum was active in the body that they moved on to stressing the subjects out, to trigger the mutation.

Vanessa had never been exposed to the Weapon X serum, so the stress of the O2 chamber didn't trigger any latent mutation.

---

It's also *possible* she doesn't *have* any mutant genes in this continuity. I'm pretty sure Ajax mentions that lots of Weapon X subjects just die before they mutate. In that case, she could be in the chamber for months with no effect. Of course, this would be a departure from the comics, and would mean they couldn't use her as Copycat in any future movies, so it's not very likely, but still, it's possible.

Comment: While your answer appears to be me correct than Praxis's, his looks nicer and addresses my comment about the sequel.

Answer (score 6):

## Differences in the duration of exposure.

As you point out in your own comment below the question, Vanessa *may* have acquired powers through her Punch Bowl exposure and it may be a set up for an expanded role for her in the sequel.  (And there *will* be a sequel, if comments by the writers, producers, and studio are any indication.)

However, there are two major differences between Deadpool's exposure to the Punch Bowl and Vanessa's:

- She was only in the Punch Bowl for a few minutes.  Wade was in the Punch Bowl for an entire weekend the first time around, during which his mutation occurred.  The length of time that one is exposed to the stress of the Punch Bowl is a plausible factor in the triggering of a mutation.
- Prior to the Punch Bowl, Wade had already been exposed for weeks to various other tortures designed to coax a mutation out of him.  Vanessa had not.